# Request URI too large when displaying an iframe

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, safari, request, httprequest

I'm trying to display a simple iframe on my site like this:

```
<iframe src="http://tritec-monitoring.solarlog-web.ch/7452.html" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" width="1024" height="1024"></iframe>
```

It looks fine on FF and Chrome but on Safari and IE it shows me an error saying:

```
Request-URI Too Large
The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.
```

I'm not sure why since the URL barely has 50 characters, or is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder if that page has an HTTP redirect? Not sure if that could still trigger the error.

Comment: Doesn't look like, I even tried shortening the URL using bitly but no luck (still worked on Chrome and FF though)